# XNA - Newbie - simple model distortion

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

Total newbie question about `XNA` (probably 3D in general).

When I render a simple Blender made cube using the following code everything looks good:

```
proj = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(90), 800f / 480f, 1f, 4000.0f);
view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, -10), new Vector3(0, 0, 10), Vector3.Up);
world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
```

But when I change the world's X value to 9 (or any other value that moves it fairly off center) the cube stretches horizontally and looks terrible:

This [links](http://www.anacapasciences.com/xna.html) shows the problem:

What I am doing wrong to get that stretching? Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Comment: That looks correct. You see it stretched because of the perspective

Comment: How would I fix that? I didn't think that using CreateOrthographic would work because I do want things that are farther away to look smaller.

Comment: Jimmy, thanks that helps some but it still streches. I must be missing something. In a proper game how would make an object that is off to the side of the screen not stretch at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the perspective distortion by using a narrower field of view. Try using, say, a 45 degree angle instead of a 90 degree angle. Since this "zooms in", you will have to place the viewMatrix further away to compensate.

edit: I just tried out how much "perspective" distortion you get with a 45 degree angle of view. I'm not sure I see any problematic distortion here.

[image]

Comment: Jimmy, thanks that helps some but it still streches. I must be missing something. In a proper game how would make an object that is off to the side of the screen not stretch at all?

Comment: this is how perspective works. you could continue to use narrower fields of view if it bothers you. the closer your field of view is to 0, the closer to orthographic your projection is.

Comment: Changing the field of view to 45 as you suggested well as adding a bit of rotation to the object got me to where I needed to be. Thanks!